# Updating Fields based on Selected Record/Spatial Location

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, enterprise-geodatabase, fields-attributes, copy

I have two SDE Feature classes, a point layer for Buildings and a Polygon layer for Building Footprints.  I am creating the Polygons on a job by job basis and would like to have the attributes for the point, inside said polygon, to carry over to the attribute fields of the polygon.  I am using ArcGis 10.2.  I have looked at Spatial Joins and tried field calculations, but I can't figure out how to update a record for the existing SDE layer.  I would like model to share with my team.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a spatial join to "Update" the original polygon layer. It creates a new polygon output. What you could do would be to first add a new field (or fields) to your polygon layer to hold the information, then perform the spatial join (the output can just be a shapefile or feature class in a file gdb) and then do a tabular join of the new spatial join output back to the original polygon layer (based on an FID or other unique value).

Then you can calculate the new fields to the values in the output from the spatial join.

The other option would be to replace your existing layer with the spatial join output but in SDE that involves a few extra steps depending on if it is registered for versioning, has locks etc. In a multi-user environment, I think it would be easier (and safer) to go with my first method.

Either way, I'd probably make a backup of the original in a file GDB before doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

@jbchurchill has answered the question of how to initially populate your existing polygons with the point data using a Spatial Join.  However, once that is done you should use Attribute Assistant to populate new features automatically during an edit session.  Just make sure to create and populate the point first.  Attribute Assistant can do the update in response to four different events: feature creation, geometry changes, attribute changes and manual triggering.  You would use the Intersecting Features method.  http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/documentation/methods-all-methods/#intersecting-feature

You can download Attribute Assistant here http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/